# Draw an inverted pie slice with Pillow

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, drawing

As the title says. How can I draw the white part of the following image, using Pillow in Python? Assuming the background can be anything, and not known at the time I write the program (but likely not uniform black, maybe not uniform at all).

[image: inverted pie slice]

The documentation of `ImageDraw` does have the `pieslice` function which does the exact opposite of what I want. And the documentation of `ImagePath` doesn't mention arcs at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using method `Image.composite` to composite two images, one is your source image and another one draw the inverted pie slice where only the white area with alpha=1, other area all with alpha=0.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def pieslice(im, w1, w2, fill="#ffffffff"):
    # Create a all transparent image
    im2 = Image.new('RGBA', (w1, w1), color="#00000000")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im2, mode="RGBA")
    d = (w1 - w2) // 2
    # Draw a nontransparent box
    draw.rectangle([(d, d), (w2 + d - 1, w2 + d - 1)], fill=fill)
    # Draw a transparent pie slice
    draw.pieslice([(d, d), (2 * w2 + d - 1, 2 * w2 + d - 1)], 180, 270, fill="#00000000")
    # Get alpha layer as mask reference in method composite
    alpha = im2.getchannel("A")
    new_im = Image.composite(im2, im, alpha)
    return new_im

w1, w2 = 200, 180
# Can use any existing square image
im = Image.new('RGBA', (w1, w1), color="#000000ff")
new_im = pieslice(im, w1, w2)
new_im.show()
```

Comment: I ended up using a similar trick, by drawing transparent a `rounded_rectangle`. Thanks for the suggestion!